# When I make the line active in the quicksort5 function, it doesn't sort well. But why?

Tags: c, algorithm, function, sorting, quicksort

Recently I was studying about quicksort,

I wrote 2 programs: One works successfully, while the other doesn't.

I tried to find why the other one is not working.(I know the reason but I want to know the reason under the reason)

The only difference between 2 programs is a line in quicksort5 function,
which is below:

```
swap( &list[ ( (backwards-forwards) /2 ) ], &list[last]  );
```

They both includes stdio.h and also have 3 functions which are called main, quicksort5, swap.

The upper lines of the program is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int quicksort5(int *, int, int);
int swap(int *, int *);
```

1) The main function is below:

```
int main()
{
    int arrayofintegers[4096];
    int n=0, quantity=0;

    printf("Please enter how many integer numbers you want to get sorted: ");
    scanf("%d",&quantity);

    if (quantity <= 0)
        return -1;

    printf("\nPlease give at max 10 digits per number.\n\n");
    while ( n<quantity ) //import the numbers
    {
        printf("the     %5d. number = ",n+1);
        scanf("%d",&arrayofintegers[n]);
        n++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    quicksort5(arrayofintegers, 0, quantity-1);

    n=0;
    while ( n<quantity ) //The numbers will be displayed.
    {
        printf("the new %5d. number =%11d\n", n+1, arrayofintegers[n]);
        n++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

2) The quicksort5 function is below:

```
int quicksort5(int *list, int forwards, int backwards)
{
    if ( forwards >= backwards )
        return 0;

    int const first   = forwards;
    int const last    = backwards;

    /* //If I make the line bellow active the function doesn't sort successfully. But I want to know the main reason in this.
    swap( &list[ ( (backwards-forwards) /2 ) ], &list[last]  ); */

    int const pivot = list[last];

    int isforwardswaiting  = 0;
    int isbackwardswaiting = 0;


    backwards--; // the pivot won't change
    while (forwards<backwards)
    {
        isforwardswaiting   = (list[forwards]  >= pivot);
        isbackwardswaiting  = (list[backwards] <  pivot);

        if(isforwardswaiting && isbackwardswaiting)
        {
            swap(&list[forwards],&list[backwards]);
            forwards++;
            backwards--;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( !(isforwardswaiting))
                forwards++;

            if ( !(isbackwardswaiting))
                backwards--;
        }
    }

    if (list[forwards] < pivot)
        forwards++;

    swap(&list[forwards],&list[last]); //placing the pivot

    /* list[first], list[first+1] ... list[forwards-2], list[forwards-1] ==> the numbers smaller than the pivot
       list[forwards]                                                    ==> the number which is the pivot
       list[forwards+1], list[forwards+2] ... list[last-1], list[last]   ==> the numbers greater than the pivot */

    quicksort5(list, first, forwards-1);
    quicksort5(list, forwards+1, last);
}
```

3) The swap function is below:

```
int swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int c=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=c;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please read about "Reserved Identifiers in C". Using leading underscores on functions is just calling for trouble. That said, please also format your code. Your indentation is inconsistent and misleading, which may well be the reason that you haven't found your mistake yourself.

Comment: Just curious as why are you placing this `void _swap(int *,int *);` inside your _qs3 function?

Comment: I thought that I can't use it without declaring it.

Comment: I have optimized and clarified it, so I'm still waiting your answers!

Comment: Check, I've posted an answer that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify the following line in your function quicksort5 :

`swap( &list[ ( (backwards-forwards) /2 ) ], &list[last]  );`

to this:

`swap( &list[ (forwards + (backwards-forwards) /2 ) ], &list[last]  );`

To understand why the first statement causes problem, consider the case when `backwards = 6` and `forwards = 4`.
So, `(backwards-forwards) /2` evaluates to 1, and the swap function swaps the element at index 6 with the one at index 1, which is not desired.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped, you have just saved my life. I'm grateful. I'm really happy now.